# overriding js file in odoo9

Tags: odoo, overriding

In mail/static/src/js/thread.js i need to change  **display_reply_icon: false**, to **True**

so overriding JS is kinda more difficult for me because i'm realy new to, so looking for help.

as my thought process is i need to create model find this js script with Xpath and then override with my own js file.

```
init: function (parent, options) {
        this._super.apply(this, arguments);
        this.options = _.defaults(options || {}, {
            display_order: ORDER.ASC,
            display_needactions: true,
            display_stars: true,
            display_document_link: true,
            display_avatar: true,
            shorten_messages: true,
            squash_close_messages: true,
            display_reply_icon: false,
        });
        this.expanded_msg_ids = [];
        this.selected_id = null;
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to load your js after the other js and then overwrite the init function.
To overwrite a function you can use extends() method.
https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/reference/javascript.html